# Estructura correcta de CASE en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
*,
CASE PORCENTAJE_CRUCE
WHEN PORCENTAJE_CRUCE >= 80.00 AND PORCENTAJE_CRUCE <= 85.99 THEN 2000
WHEN PORCENTAJE_CRUCE >= 86.00 AND PORCENTAJE_CRUCE <= 90.99 THEN 3000
WHEN PORCENTAJE_CRUCE >= 91.00 THEN 5000
ELSE 0
END AS PAGO_INCENTIVO
FROM #AR_PORCENTAJE
```

y el siguiente error:

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Supongo que la condicion que estoy poniendo despues del `WHEN` es incorrecta, como seria la manera correcta para agregar estas condiciones despues del `WHEN` ?

Comment: ¿No tendrá que ver el espacio en el AS PAGO INCENTIVO y si le pones AS [PAGO INCENTIVO]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La expresión `CASE` en SQL Server tiene 2 formas, en la primera comparas una columna con condiciones de igualdad:

```
CASE Columna
     WHEN valor1 THEN resultado1
     WHEN valor2 THEN resultado2
     …
     ELSE resultadox
END
```

O si quieres comparaciones más elaboradas que no sean simplemente la igualdad de una única columna con algún valor:

```
CASE
    WHEN columna BETWEEN valor1 AND valor2 THEN resultado
    WHEN ….
END
```

Básicamente, en tu caso simplemente tienes que quitar `PORCENTAJE_CRUCE` inmediatamente después de `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
*,
CASE 
    WHEN PORCENTAJE_CRUCE >= 80.00 AND PORCENTAJE_CRUCE <= 85.99 THEN 2000
    WHEN PORCENTAJE_CRUCE >= 86.00 AND PORCENTAJE_CRUCE <= 90.99 THEN 3000
    WHEN PORCENTAJE_CRUCE >= 91.00 THEN 5000
ELSE 0
END AS PAGO_INCENTIVO
FROM #AR_PORCENTAJE;
```

Comment: @shop350 puedes mostrar un ejemplo de eso?

Comment: @shop350 ese `CASE` en efecto quitó la columna que yo decía, por lo que no entiendo bien tu comentario

Comment: Ah tienes razón ya vi la diferencia.